# Expectation fails, when testing code in javascript fetch.then block

Tags: angular, jasmine, fetch, karma-runner

I try to verify that `window.open()` is called within a `then` block. Here is a minimal example.

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

function openWindow() {
  const linksource = `data:application/pdf;base64,somePDF`;
  fetch(linksource).then(() => {
    window.open();
  });
}

describe('Asynchronus Testing', () => {
  it('opens a window', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Dont actually open a window
    window.open = () => window;
    spyOn(window, 'open');

    openWindow();
    tick();

    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

`window.open()` is actually called, but the expectation fails:

```
Error: Expected spy open to have been called.
```

The `tick()` is not helping even if I give it more time. I guess it is specific to `fetch` because the `Promise.resolve().then()` block works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing with `fakeAsync/tick` where the `tick` does not control some promises.

I would spy on `fetch` and make it return a random promise.

```
describe('Asynchronus Testing', () => {
  it('opens a window', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Dont actually open a window
    window.open = () => window;
    spyOn(window, 'open');
    // !! spy on window fetch and return a random promise
    spyOn(window, 'fetch').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));

    openWindow();
    tick();

    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

It should hopefully work with that modification. You should also not be making Http calls in a unit test (general rule).